# Views in Linear layout don't align properly

Tags: java, android, xml

Following code produces the result in the blueprint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/marker_shape">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/marker_header">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widget_1_header_from"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/widget_1_refresh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/quantum_ic_refresh_white_24"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/widget_1_list"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see: the TextView gets displayed beneath the Button. They need to go next to each other. How do I fix this?

[image: blueprint]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Change your button's height to `wrap_content`.

or:

2. change your textview height to `match_parent`.